# Node.js; list strings from JSON file in order

Tags: node.js, json, chatbot, vk

I have file users.json, which contain, among others, data like this:

```json
[
  {
     "nick": "user123",
     "active24": 579
     ...
  }, {
     "nick": "nick",
     "active24": 259
     ...
  }
]
```

I want to make leaderboard, showing top 10 users nicks (from uknown max value of users), based on ther "active24" (from biggest to smallest). I can do it using array, but problem is that bot can't send it using vk-io (reason is not important, so i don't describe it much here, but please, do not save final input as array, but as variables or etc). I want output like:

```
Var_top1 = `${nick}: ${active24}`;
Var_top2 = `${nick}: ${active24}`;
Var_top3 = `${nick}: ${active24}`;
...
Var_top10 = `${nick}: ${active24}`;
```

P.S sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want something like this?

```js
const data = [
  {
    nick: "user111",
    active24: 579
  },
  {
    nick: "nick222",
    active24: 0
  },
  {
    nick: "nick333",
    active24: 84
  },
  {
    nick: "nick444",
    active24: 9459
  }
];

  const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => b.active24 - a.active24);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted)); 
  //[{"nick":"nick444","active24":9459},{"nick":"user111","active24":579},{"nick":"nick333","active24":84},{"nick":"nick222","active24":0}]
  const top1 = sorted[0];
  const top2 = sorted[1];
  const top3 = sorted[2];
  const top4 = sorted[3];
```

Comment: Array.sort does not generate a new array, but instead modifies the content of the array where it is applied. In this case, the variable 'sorted' is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Order the array using a methodology such as
[array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Once the array has all members sorted, you just need to print them `array[0].nick + ":" + array[0].active24`

```
let jsonObject = [
    {
        "nick": "user123",
        "active24": 579
    },
    {
        "nick": "user234",
        "active24": 1
    },
    {
        "nick": "nick",
        "active24": 259
    }
];

// Orders the array
jsonObject.sort((firstElem, secondElem) => {
    if (firstElem.active24 > secondElem.active24) return 1;
    if (firstElem.active24 < secondElem.active24) return -1;
    return 0;
})

// Prints the entire ordered array 
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2));

// Prints the nick and the active24 value
for (let i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
    console.log(jsonObject[i].nick + ":" + jsonObject[i].active24);
}
```